# Menu com ancora href, não funciona quando está na mesma página

Tags: jquery, menu, ancora

Tenho menu que fica em um include e se eu estou na home e clico em uma das opções vai certinho para a página desejada, só que quando estou na própria página só funciona o primeiro link que é o que eu estou o restante não. Tem que colocar algum jquery HREF para funcionar?

**MENU**

```
            <ul>
                <li><a title="unica">unica</a></li>
                <li><a href="unica.php#tabs-1" title="Histórico e Missão">Histórico e Missão</a></li>
                <li><a href="unica.php#tabs-2" title="Equipe">Equipe</a></li>
                <li><a href="unica.php#tabs-3" title="Conselheiros">Conselheiros</a></li>
                <li><a href="unica.php#tabs-4" title="Sindicatos">Sindicatos</a></li>
                <li><a href="unica.php#tabs-5" title="Contatos">Contatos</a></li>
            </ul>

<div id="tabs-1"></div>
<div id="tabs-2"></div>
<div id="tabs-3"></div>
```

**CÓDIGO JQUERY**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("UL LI A").click(function(){
        $("#tabs").attr("href", "http://localhost/unica/unica.php");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Não ficou claro. Poderia explicar melhor?

Comment: Este menu que eu coloquei ai vai aparecer em todo o site pq eles está em um include, quando a pessoas entram no site e clica em qualquer link dele ele vai pra outra página na ancora que eu determinei ali no lik, só que se a pessoas quiser ir para outra ancora estando já na página onde ela existe o menu não funciona